# Golang - How to set value through pointer when pointer is interface{}

Tags: go

I am very new to Golang and I am trying to set value through pointer. Normally I can just do it as such

```
p := &i         // point to i
*p = 21         // set i through the pointer
```

But what if pointer is a interface{}

```
package main

import "fmt"

func doStuff(q interface{}) {
    *q = MyStruct{2}
}

type MyStruct struct {
    f1 int
}

func main() {
    ms := MyStruct{1}
    doStuff(&ms)
    fmt.Printf("Hello, playground: %v\n", ms)
}
```

Say I don't can't modify the `doStuff` function to take in a `*MyStruct`. Is it possible to set ms through pointer q to have new value `MyStruct{2}`?
 I am getting this error 
`invalid indirect of q (type interface {})` How can I solve this?

Comment: Use a type assertion: `*(q.(*MyStruct)) = MyStruct{2}`

Comment: awesome possum :) thanks

Comment: `*(*MyStruct)((*[2]unsafe.Pointer)(unsafe.Pointer(&q))[1]) = MyStruct{2}`